# Cloudformation: API: s3:CreateBucket Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I am getting

> API: s3:CreateBucket Access Denied

in CloudFormation template, but when I try the same code to create the S3 bucket, in another barebones template, it works

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion : '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: 'Testing'

Parameters:
  TagCostCenter:
    Type: String
  TagDeveloper:
    Type: String
  TagProject:
    Type: String

Resources:
  S3Artifacts:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-artifacts
      AccessControl: Private
      Tags:
        - Key: Cost Center
          Value: !Ref TagCostCenter
        - Key: Developer
          Value: !Ref TagDeveloper
        - Key: Project
          Value: !Ref TagProject
```

What is wrong? The stack used to work, all I did was add in the S3 bucket

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @ChrisPaton I cant remember specifically, but perhaps yes. Can you check if your user or the role CloudFormation runs in has the CreateBucket permission?

Comment: Yeah I had that permission. I think it had to do with ACL permissions, etc. I just added admin in the end. Will revisit at some stage but the error is misleading as I needed permissions involved in creating a bucket (ACL, CORS, etc.) but not specifically s3:CreateBucket.

Comment: @JiewMeng any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

You should have permission to create S3 bucket. Add `CreateBucket` policy to your IAM user.

Comment: I do have I can create the S3 bucket if I do it in another CloudFormation template ... not sure why ... I dont expect other resources in CloudFormation template to affect the results of this? Esp, since its an access denied error

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the s3:PutBucketAcl permission.  Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the error because the IAM role that I was using had a policy that had a ***CreateBucket*** action but the action was referencing the wrong ***Resource***. I added the action to the right resource and the error was solved.